# Delphi - System tray icon not opening the application back up

Tags: windows, delphi, system-tray

i am using the code below. I want to hide the application, but show it in the system try(works), but then when i try to show the main form on left mouse click down, nothing happens. can you guys please help? i have included just about all the code.

Main Form Code:

```
unit Main_Unit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,shellApi,AppEvnts;



type
  TMain = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
   TrayIconData: TNotifyIconData;
    procedure TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Main: TMain;

const
  WM_ICONTRAY = WM_USER + 1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Functions;

procedure TMain.TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.lParam of
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    begin
      ShowMessage('Left button clicked - let''s SHOW the Form!');
      Main.Show;
    end;
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    begin
      ShowMessage('Right button clicked - let''s HIDE the Form!');
      Main.Hide;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
with TrayIconData do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf();
    Wnd := Handle;
    uID := 0;
    uFlags := NIF_MESSAGE + NIF_ICON + NIF_TIP;
    uCallbackMessage := WM_ICONTRAY;
    hIcon := Application.Icon.Handle;
    StrPCopy(szTip, Application.Title);
  end;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @TrayIconData);
end;

procedure TMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @TrayIconData);
end;

end.
```

Initializing Code:

```
program Test;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Main_Unit in 'Main_Unit.pas' {Main},
  Functions in 'Functions.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TMain, Main);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Thank You

Comment: So you're saying that pressing the right button hides the main window, but pressing the left button does not re-show that window?

Comment: @RobKennedy I cannot execute any of the 2 functions. i click on the icon, but nothing happens at all.

Comment: @Davidheffernan I will post the full code now. both the initializing code and the main form code

Comment: You did not check return values for errors

Comment: @davidheffernan explain a little what you mean please?

Comment: When you call a Win32 function it's return value indicates whether or not it succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a message handler, but you did not connect to to the message ID. In the declaration of the form type, change the `TrayMessage` declaration to be:

```
procedure TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ICONTRAY;
```

Beyond that I have the following comments:

1. Always check Win32 function return values for errors.
2. You write `Main.Show` and `Main.Hide` in a `TMain` method. You should simply remove `Main.` and call these methods on the implicit `Self` object.
3. Use bitwise `or` rather than arithmethic `+` to combine flags.
4. You use the form handle for the notification icon. If the form is re-created, your icon will be orphaned. Instead you need to use a stable window handle obtained by a call to `AllocateHWnd`.

Comment: The tell tale sign of no blue dots in the gutter next to the message handler was quite obvious once I got this in the IDE ......

Comment: i get an error Unknown directive: 'message' when i try to compile on the following code:

procedure TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ICONTRAY;

Comment: You are not doing what I said. Your put it in the implementation section and actually your code says: `procedure TMain.TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ICONTRAY;`. You have to put it in the declaration of the form type, in the interface section. Also, when you paste code, paste the code from your editor at the line that gives the error.  ;-)

Comment: You my man are brilliant!

Thanks for the help. Seems to be working fine now.